# I'm unable to access any .vdi files over the network

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, sftp

I have two Arch workstations.  I want to be able to run VirtualBox on Machine A, and access the .vdi files stored on a storage drive on Machine B.  I'm sure I'm not connecting the two machines properly to do this, but I'm not sure how.

VirtualBox gives me VERR_NET_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED opening image file /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=arch36,user=nick/home/nick/VirtualBoxVMs/Windows/Windows.vdi.

Originally I browsed to the folder via the "Connect to Server" option in the file manager, specifying SSH on 22, and using the correct login information.  I can browse through the file manager to see the files.

Comment: You need to mount the network location and provide the user running VBox write access to it per this [discussion](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=33558)

Comment: I'm trying to do that, but I keep getting "mount error(13): Permission Denied".  I'm running the command `sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.65/run/media/nick/Storage /mnt/dest -o user="user",pass="pass"`.  I've tried all of the options of sec= to no effect.

Comment: It sounds like the user your using does not have read permissions.  You will have to resolve that problem before you can mount the drive.

Comment: Thats the thing, I made sure to chmod 777 the directory to share, and made write permissions yes in smb.conf.  I'm not sure of where else to open permissions.